# About the node gm image opactity

Tags: node.js, imagemagick

I want to use node package `gm` to generate a image :

```
var fs = require('fs'),
gm = require('gm').subClass({imageMagick: true});

......

gm(200, 200, "#ddff99f3")
  .fontSize(200)
  .fill("#FFF")
  .drawText(27, 173, "U")
  .write("test.jpg", function (err) {
    console.log("OK")
});
```

Now I want to make the text `U`'s opacity to be 0.5(not the whole image's opacity). So what should I do?

Comment: Try changing the `fill` to `fill("#fff8")`.

Comment: I have put it as a properly explained answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In writing the `fill` as `#FFF` you are essentially specifying it in `RGB` format. If you want to specify an opacity as well, you should move to an `RGBA` specification so that you are also providing an Opacity/Alpha setting. In hex terms, `8` is more or less half of hex `F`, so try using:

```
gm(200, 200, "#ddff99f3")
  .fontSize(200)
  .fill("#FFF8")                        <--- I have added `8` for Alpha/Opacity here
  .drawText(27, 173, "U")
  .write("test.jpg", function (err) {
    console.log("OK")
});
```

Comment: Good,I just use `.fill("rgba(255,255,255,0.8)")`